# Getting an error when trying to create data using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying create a new post using the `post` method in `Http` library. I have an `input` box in the template and if anyone add a post through that `input` box will that `post` in the list.

But I am getting an error in `post.id=response.json().id`. Please find the code below.

```
posts:any[];
private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
constructor(private http : HttpClient) {
http.get(this.url).subscribe( (Response: any[]) => {
this.posts = Response;
} )
}
addPost(postTitle:HTMLInputElement){
let post:any = {input : postTitle.value}
postTitle.value = '';
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post))
.subscribe( response => {
post.id = response.json().id;
this.posts.splice(0, 0, post)
//console.log( response );
})
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is returning an object with id and I want to show that particular post with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unlike the old `HttpModule`, the `HttpClientModule` provides the json response back

so, you can directly set `post.id = response.id` since response is already a valid parsed `json`

**Update**

See working code below : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tmcvj?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="addPost(input)" #input placeholder="Enter Post Here......." class="form-control">
    <ul class="list-group mt-3">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of posts | slice:0:8">{{ post.title }}</li>
    </ul>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  posts: any[];
  private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get(this.url)
    .subscribe( (response: any[]) => {
      this.posts = response;
    })
  }

  addPost(input: HTMLInputElement){
    let post:any = {
      title: input.value
    } // since post should be an object and you are displaying post.title in the list
    this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post))
      .subscribe( (data:any) => {
        console.log(data);
        post.id = data.id;
        this.posts = [post,...this.posts]; // adds the new post to the top of this.posts so that the slice(0,8) will contain the updated value
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error - Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: console.log(response) and see what the object is and if the response has the id

Comment: Getting an object with id:101                                                                                              {id: 101}

Comment: then response.id should be available too!

Comment: Please check the link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fn8rtd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html. If i try to add a title by typing the name in the input box that title should appear in the top of the list. When typing something and pressing enter see the console.

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU see the updated code above. it is working

Comment: The problem was not in the id, the problem was elsewhere, it was easier to find once you shared the blitz

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU, consider upvote/ accepting the answer if it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is being caused by `json()` specifically. `json()` is something that you would usually do with `fetch()` to parse an `application/json` body. You wouldn't need to do this with `HttpClient` as it automatically parses JSON for you. Try changing:

```
post.id = response.json().id
```

To just:

```
post.id = response.id
```

**Update:**

You are indicating an error of `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.`. This is happening because you are not providing a [type for the response](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response) and TypeScript does not know what properties exist on the resolved payload. You can get around this by doing:

```
post.id = response['id']
// or
// post.id = (response as any).id
```

That being said, instead you should make an interface or class that represents the structure of your payload and provide that to the HttpClient call.

```
interface MyInterface {
  id: number;
}

// ...

this.http.post<MyInterface>(this.url, JSON.stringify(post))
  .subscribe(response => {
    post.id = response.id;
    // ...
  });
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. While making the change getting this error.                 
      Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU I updated an answer to help with the `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.` error.

Comment: now its showing - Cannot create property 'id' on string 'sasas'

Comment: I don’t know what sasas is. Is that something returned from your server? Is that something from another component in this Angular app? You need to provide more information. The answer above resolves the specific Angular/TypeScript issue you described.

Comment: Basically, I have a input box and a list of titles getting from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. I am getting this titles using get method of http. Now if i type something in the input box and press enter I want that title to add on top that list of titles. When i am typing a text in the box and pressing enter it is showing Cannot create property 'id' on string 'new title'. In this method I am using post method.

Comment: Please don’t put complex code into comments. How about instead you make a working example at https://stackblitz.com/ and share the url in your question. That way myself or others can provide a working solution.

Comment: Can you please check the link and let me know - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fn8rtd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient always provides json object as a response so no need to use ".json()" method to parse it again.
Just use:

```
post.id = response.id;
```

Comment: Please check the link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fn8rtd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts If i try to add a title by typing the name in the input box that title should appear in the top of the list. When typing something and pressing enter see the console